# css boxshadow property

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to extend the animate function of jquery to support the CSS box shadow-property which  can animate the color, the x- and y-offset, the blur-radius and spread-radius.How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can not animate the colors with `animate`, you need the [jQuery Color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) in order to do that.

Comment: thanks for answer but after my some research i found the following one useful
http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.animate-shadow.js_0.txt